# Redirect Query String from Site Root to Sub-Domain Site Root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect

```
http://example.com/?download_invoice=true&attendee_id=28916&r_id=504-55803a183a0cf
```

to

```
http://secure.example.com/?download_invoice=true&attendee_id=28916&r_id=504-55803a183a0cf
```

but aren't having any luck. I'm able to redirect Query Strings from sub-directories just fine using this syntax:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sub-directory/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://secure.example.com/sub-directory/ [L,R=301]
```

but can't figure out how to do it from the site root. Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match host name in `RewriteCond` and pattern `^$` in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://secure.%1/ [L,R=301]
```

`QUERY_STRING` gets forwarded automatically to target URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I should have clarified, I ONLY want to redirect if there is a query string. It is a Wordpress site, so I can't redirect everything, the goal is to only redirect if there is a query string after the web root (i.e. http://example.com/?anything=1235). Would that change your answer? Thanks again for the help